# UIAlert visual slow-down when UINavigationController popping

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I have a UIAlert appear just before the UINavigationController pops a view controller off the stack.  This causes a very visible slow-down; the current view darkens, pauses, slides to the new view, and then at last the UIAlert appears.

The slow-down is entirely undesirable; it looks terrible.  Programmatically I need to fire the UIAlert before the view controller transition (although I do *not* need to wait for user interaction w/the UIAlert to continue) because that's where the data is.

So do I (a) make the data accessible to after-the-view-controller-pop and fire UIAlert then, (b) add some sort of time or function delay to the UIAlert so that it fires after-the-view-controller-pop, or (c) some otehr good suggestion?

Comment: Can you have the view controller that will appear so the showing of the `UIAlert`?

Comment: [OP] I could, except that the data I want to stuff into the message for the alert is not global, so I'd have to expose it with great reluctance.

Comment: Or you can pass it to the view controller that is being loaded. The view controller can then treat it like any other data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodThatShowsAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Comment: [OP] A very intriguing idea.  I'm having the alert pop up in a block of code and not as an exterior method, and as such it uses local ivars in the message text that I am reluctant to expose.  Is there a way I could use a single statement that creates and shows the UIAlert and stuff that in as the @selector?